# YouTube videos search with the API V3 using curl returning error

Tags: php, curl, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I'm currently using this code to do a search by GET request in jQuery:

```
$.get("https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=c8a3_9ecqBA&key=MYAPIKEY&part=snippet,contentDetails", function(data) {
    console.log(data);
});
```

And the data is returned correctly in the console. But I want to do the same thing in PHP (using AJAX), so I've been trying:

```
// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();

// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?q=Eminem&key=MYAPIKEY&part=snippet&type=video&maxResults=20",
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => "Simple Test"
));

// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);

// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

echo $resp;
```

But the response is:

```
 {
  "error": {
      "errors": [
           {
              "domain": "usageLimits",
              "reason": "ipRefererBlocked",
              "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed.",
              "extendedHelp": "https://console.developers.google.com"
            }
      ],
      "code": 403,
      "message": "There is a per-IP or per-Referer restriction configured on your API key and the request does not match these restrictions. Please use the Google Developers Console to update your API key configuration if request from this IP or referer should be allowed."
      }
 }
```

How to fix it?

Comment: It's my public API Key, and is configured to work only on configured domains, so, I don't see problem to share this...

Comment: You can setting header's `Referer` with `CURLOPT_REFERER`

Comment: It's worked @Federico . Thx bro! Make an answer so I can mark it as resolved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason of the error is that the request need an enabled Referer. You can  set it by adding `CURLOPT_REFERER` options to your `curl_setopt_array` configuration.